# SQL server Error 4060

Tags: sql-server-2005, security

4060 "Server rejected the connection; Access to selected database has been denied".

How can I troubleshoot this error?

Comment: from where are you trying to connect to the sql server?
if from code, then it would be good to give us the connection string that you are using

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have permission to access the database using the credentials that you are supplying? What provider are you trying to use?  TCP/IP, Named Pipes?  Has that provider been enabled?  Is there a firewall in place and have you opened up the port to the client?  Does this happen intermittently?  If so, do you have enough licenses available when the error occurs? You might want to check the server error logs (and your client event log, too) for more information.

Answer (score 9):

This error also occurs if the Database not exists

so make sure that there is a database with the name you provided in
Catalog=MyDB

Answer (score 2):

User credentials are ok, but user doesn't have the right to connect to the given database, you should grant him all rights needed...

Comment: what happens is that the user/pass are provided to sql, AND credentials are correct, AND before connecting the user to the database requested for the connection, sql tries to connect the user to the user's default database, which turns to be, in Haranadh's case not granted to the user in question. that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely don't have the necessary permissions to access the database, or there isn't a database which correspond to the information you specified.

Comment: And how would you change the information you specify? I'm getting the same error when trying to update a table through the Linked Table Manager.